# Assignment in Hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have below query in which i need to assign one table column value to another table column.

*Query:*

```
SELECT A.aval,B.bval,B.bval1 FROM A JOIN B ON (A.aval = B.bval)
```

How do I assign one table column value to another table column in Hive?

Have tried

```
 SELECT A.aval,B.bval,B.bval1, A.aval = B.bval1 FROM A JOIN B ON (A.aval = B.bval)
```

In results:

> A.aval = B.bval1, returning false since its not assigning to A.aval.

Comment: You cannot assign in the select statement. What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to write in a table ?

So You have to create a table (for example C) which contains all the fields you need.
And then you do :

```
INSERT [OVERWRITE] INTO TABLE C
SELECT A.aval,B.bval,B.bval1, A.aval 
FROM A 
JOIN B ON (A.aval = B.bval)
```

The result of the select will be inserted in the table C

Comment: Thanks Junayy for your response. 
No, I want to assign one table column value to another table column.
something like this, select A.aval=B.bval from A join B on (A.aval=B.bval).

Answer (score 0):

insert overwrite table c SELECT A.aval,B.bval,B.bval1 FROM A JOIN B ON (A.aval = B.bval)